# How to change the color of chrome tab headers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and want to know how can I change the color of chrome tab headers.

[image]

Like, how can I color the facebook tab to green, and the other tab to yellow.

I am new to chrome extension development so not really sure if google even allows it.
In internet, all I could find is for "Chrome for android" and I want to develop this for desktop chrome.

Only a direction is required to get me started.

Comment: Chrome extensions can't do that.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the input. If I leave it for now, can I do some work-around to color them ? Like changing some HTML attributes, so when a page loads, I can change the DOM in such a way I get to see colors. All I am trying to do is, make a chrome extension which can be used to identify the tabs when many tabs are opened and we cant see the titles. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: Perhaps you can change the icon, highlight the tab (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-highlight), or prepend some character to the tab title.